# Fortinet SSL VPN Ubuntu 19.04 sha256sum self-signed host certificate

Tags: networking, vpn, ssl

Fortinet host has self-signed cert.

Ubuntu 19.04 network management allows creation of a Fortinet connection.

There is a field for the sha256sum of the host self-signed cert.

I have used openssl s_client to get the cert and sha256sum to sum it many ways but none of them get me connected.

Tips on getting this field in the correct form so I can connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run openfortivpn at the command line and it will show the sha256 digest of the certificate. `man openfortivpn` for the arguments.